# array map react firebase redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

Im pretty new to react , i use react firebase redux , how can i display my questions array who return an object , what is the best way to achieve this ? i want to return them like list :

```
import { compose, withHandlers,withProps } from 'recompose'
import { firebaseConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase'
import { Alerts,spinnerWhileLoading } from '@components'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'




export default compose(
  firebaseConnect([
    { type: 'once', path: '/questions' }
  ]),


  withHandlers({
    logout: ({ firebase }) => () =>
      firebase.logout().catch(err => Alerts.danger(err.message))
  }),

  connect((state, props) => ({
    questions: state.firebase.data.questions, 

// questions return Object {
  "-LrP3EkfZ8fCgkNycJ2-": Object {
    "question": "De déféré déféré",
    "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
  },
  "-LrP4P3fQDK6DnS1hxDt": Object {
    "question": "De déféré déféré",
    "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
  },
  "-LrPNX18hQLL-OjHWC3R": Object {
    "question": "Dddededed",
    "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12",
  },
}
      })),
  spinnerWhileLoading(['questions'])


)
```

to my index.js like :

```
let Questions = ({ navigation: { navigate }, logout,questions}) => (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
{console.log(questions)}
//question array
<li question ="" />
<li question ="" />
//question array
</View>
export default enhancer(Questions)
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you should:

1. Save each of your questions in collection, named like questions. Each on is a document.
2. On fetch questions, you must return array of objects with each data and id, something like:

```js
query.onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
  let arrayToReturn = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    const objectData = {
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data()
    };
  arrayToReturn.push(objectData);
  });
return arrayToReturn;
```

```
You will have array like this:
[
  {
    "id": "-LrP3EkfZ8fCgkNycJ2-"
    "question": "De déféré déféré",
    "user": "9jNkvzr0chgPi0SC6rXMlVWdOF12"
  },
  ...
]
```

3. Map array and return `<li />` for each question.

Let me know if it helps you :)